# php iterating over an array to fetch account data

Tags: php, arrays, loops, indexing, iteration

I have this page set up that logs into a site for me and downloads fresh content to my server. I would like it to do this for a number of accounts, continuing to do so indefinitely as long as my browser has the page open.

In the script, I create the connection like this:`$connection = new Connection('myusername','pass');`

That said, I would like to take my creds out, and then place variables there. above that I would like to declare an array of username/password combos, but I dont know how to access the indexes. The array would be similar to this:

```
<?php
$accounts = array(
"foo" => "bar",
"bar" => "foo!",
"foo" => "foo"
"bar" => "bar"
//100   => -100,
//-100  => 100,
);
//var_dump($array);
?>
```

And so the loop should be something like

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<=count($accounts); $i++) {
//set the first value to username, *****
//set the second value to password *****
//create my connection based on these variables
//do the rest of my steps
}
?>
```

The lines with the asterisks are the lines I am unsure of. With the array above, are the elements stored as $accounts[0][0] == 'foo', $accounts[0][0] == 'bar' ?

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, a `foreach` loop seems more appropriate (and easier):

```
foreach ($accounts as $username => $password) {
    $connection = new Connection($username, $password);
    // Further processing...
}
```

Comment: this looks painstakingly obvious now. I have implimented it, and tested. Works like a charm.